# Interpretation of the meaning of a quote of J. C. Shairp

Tags: quotes

I wish to understand the boldfaced part of the sentence *The true poet is not an eccentric creature, not a mere artist living only for art, not a dreamer or a dilettante, sipping the nectar of existence, while **he keeps aloof from its deeper interests**.*, which belongs to J. C. Shairp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key to the meaning is *dilettante,* which [ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/dilettante?q=dilettante) describes as

> A person who cultivates an area of interest, such as the arts, without real commitment or knowledge.

Sharp uses the image of a bee flitting from flower to flower as a metaphor for a dilettante’s lightweight and possibly fickle interest in the arts (“the nectar of existence”).

There is no attempt to immerse himself in the arts, to pursue a deeper interest. The dilettante disdains that. Using the word *aloof,* “conspicuously uninvolved” [[ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/aloof)], Sharp indicates that the dilettante actually feels that such an involvement is beneath his dignity.

A true poet, on the other hand, jumps in with both feet.